# javascript simple Audio Volume meter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I am looking for a very simple audio meter implementation in Javascript. 
I came across this:
http://www.smartjava.org/examples/webaudio/example2.html

This is a good example, but unfortunately, it is using Web Audio API (here is more info): http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound

This works fine, but not on all platform; for example IE has no support for it whatsoever. 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api

Any idea how can do this in HTML5 using javascript?

I want it to be really simple. I don't need for it to be accurately representative of the volume. All I want is just to be able to have some bar moving, when the audio is on.

Comment: You can try [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS/demos/testSuite)